# jQuery Accordion Custom Icon Not Showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to use a custom image for my jQuery accordian iconOpen and iconClosed classes.  The iconClosed image is displaying fine but I can't seem to get the iconOpen image to use my own custom image.

Here's my code CSS code:

```
.ui-icon.iconClosed {
    background:         url('path to my image') no-repeat -0px;
    background-size:    12px;
    width:              12px;
    height:             12px;
}

ui-icon.iconOpen {
    background-image:           url('path to my image') no-repeat -0px;
    background-size:    12px;
    width:              12px;
    height:             12px;
}
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var icons = {
        header:         "iconClosed",    // custom icon class
        activeHeader:   "iconOpen"      // custom icon class
    };

    $( '#stateList' ).accordion({

        collapsible:    true,
        icons:  icons
    });
```

Comment: you forgot the dot before the name clase and use backround instead of background-image: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dpp9up1c/)